# In a modal operator event timer , Why does changing the update seconds not make any difference

Tags: python, time, modal-dialog, operator-keyword

In a modal operator, the line :

```
self._timer = wm.event_timer_add(0.1, window=context.window)
```

From docs - 
time_step (float in [0, inf]) – Time Step, Interval in seconds between timer events

However changing the 0.1 to 1, or 500 has no visual effect.

Is this a bug, or am I understanding the usage incorrectly ?

Comment: are you refering to this: https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.WindowManager.html

Comment: yes, time_step (float in [0, inf]) – Time Step, Interval in seconds between timer events

Comment: Could you provide more context (code)?

Answer (score 0):

The conclusions that you can derive from this depends on how are you measuring the results.

It happens that a modal operator provides an Event object, which is responsible for managing all kinds of events, not just timers, so this object will also react to all user input and call the modal function whenever a new event is detected.

What is wrong is to assume that because there's one timer set for the operator, the modal function will only be called when a timer event is produced.

The modal function will be called on all possible events. Even when you only move the mouse, there are events being passed to the modal function.

The 'time_step' parameter works as expected, but you have to filter the timer event from all other possible events within the modal function, to ensure that you are only referring to the timer ones. This way you can get an accurate idea of the time it takes for the function to be called, and not to measure with false positives.

To filter the timer events just use this in your modal function:

```
if event.type == "TIMER":

    # your code() to execute on timer events
```

As best practice recommendation, try to reserve the use of the modal function to all event decisions, including when to cancel or sucessfully finish the running operator.

Never include code unrelated to events within the modal function, or you will find it growing like crazy when you have a bit of complexity.